# How to use object name in paste?

Tags: r, paste, gsub

I'm trying to create a user-defined function which has as one output a network object that is named similarly to the input dataframe used in the function.  Something like this.

```
node_attributes <- function(i){ #i is dataframe
j <- network(i)
##some other function stuff##
(i,'network',sep = '_')) <- j 
}
```

The idea is to create add '_network' onto the ***i*** variable, which is meant to be a dataframe. So if my orignial dataframe is **foo_bar_data**, my output would be: **foo_bar_data_network**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `assign`

```
j <- network(i)
assign(paste0(i,'network',sep = '_'), j)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the name of input variables with `deparse(substitute(argname))`.

```
func <- function(x){
  depsrse(substitute(x))
}

func(some_object)
## [1] "some_object"
```

I am not completely sure how you want to use the name of the input, so I used something similar to the answer of @JackStat

```
node_attributes <- function(i){
  output_name <- paste(deparse(substitute(i)), 'network', sep = '_')
  ## I simplified this since I don't know what the function network is
  j <- i
  assign(output_name, j, envir = parent.frame())
}

node_attributes(mtcars)
head(mtcars_network)
##                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

That said I don't really see any reason to code like this. Normally, returning the output from the function is the recommended way.